# combine two -filter_complex command together

Tags: ffmpeg

Below, I have two ffmpeg commands (1, 2) to be combined into (3).

1. add sounds from `1.mp3` and `1.3gp` into muted `1.mp4`

code works without error:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 1.3gp -i 1.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[1]adelay=640|640[s1];[0][s1]amix=2[mixout];" \
  -map 2:v -map [mixout] -c:v copy result.mp4
```

2. add watermark to top-right of `1.mp4`

code works without error:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png \
  -filter_complex "overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w:y=1" \
   result.mp4
```

3. combine above two commands into one

**My code fails**

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 1.3gp -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png \
  -filter_complex "[1]adelay=640|640[s1];[0][s1]amix=2[mixout];[2:v][3]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w:y=1[outv]" \
  -map [outv] -map [mixout] -c:v copy result.mp4
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 1.3gp -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png \
  -filter_complex "[1]adelay=640|640[s1];[0][s1]amix=2[mixout];
                   [2:v][3]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w:y=1[outv]" \
  -map [outv] -map [mixout] result.mp4
```

If you're filtering the video stream e.g. adding an overlay, then you can't copy that video stream.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me out again! 

One more quick question: it takes much longer time to add watermark comparing to merge audios. 

Is there any valid reason? From a novice's point of view, adding a static picture shouldn't have taken much effort, no?

Comment: The main time goes to re-encoding the video, not the overlay itself.

Comment: I see... I just did googled, it seems there is no way to avoid this compensation. But it is irrelevant on this thread. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome job, thank you! Just a quick note, my use case was different as I wanted to sequentially combine parts of an mp3 file and then add a delay to the second part, but this solution also helped me resolve that. Here's the command I ended up using if anyone's interested:

ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 1.5 -i file.mp3 -ss 3 -to 5 -i file.mp3 -vn -filter_complex '[1:a]adelay=640ms|640ms[a2]; [0:a][a2] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [outa]' -map '[outa]' out.mp3